# Undo/Redo in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

A program I am creating includes a `QTextEdit` part. I want to perform the following feature:

1. When I try to press on a `QAction` item playing a role of **Undo** then
   when the end of the track history of **Undo** will be achieved **the concrete value (either `bool` or `int`)** must be returned. After the successful execution of that (the above command) as I guess another commands will be implemented.
2. The same things must be performed for **Redo**.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read the `QTextEdit` [document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#undo) you will find all the actions you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Qt `QTextEdit` [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), you can find the `redo` and `undo` actions. also you can test if the `redo` or `undo` are avaliable via the `redoAvailable` and `undoAvailable` signals.

To implement the actions you can register using the signal/slot.

For example:

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton *poUndo     = new QPushButton("Undo", this);
    QPushButton *poRedo     = new QPushButton("Redo", this);
    QTextEdit   *poTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    QHBoxLayout *poHlayout  = new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel * poLabelRedoAvaliable = new QLabel(this);
    QLabel * poLabelUndoAvaliable = new QLabel(this);


    // add undo/redo buttons
    poHlayout->addWidget(poRedo);
    poHlayout->addWidget(poUndo);

    QVBoxLayout *poVLayout  = new QVBoxLayout;
    poVLayout->addWidget(poTextEdit); // add text edit
    poVLayout->addLayout(poHlayout);

    // redo/undo avaliable status
    poVLayout->addWidget(poLabelRedoAvaliable);
    poVLayout->addWidget(poLabelUndoAvaliable);

    // main central widget
    QWidget *poCentral  = new QWidget(this);
    poCentral->setLayout(poVLayout);
    this->setCentralWidget(poCentral);

    // register the undo/redo actions actions
    connect(poUndo, &QPushButton::clicked,  poTextEdit, &QTextEdit::undo);
    connect(poRedo, &QPushButton::clicked,  poTextEdit, &QTextEdit::redo);

    connect(poTextEdit, &QTextEdit::redoAvailable,
            [poLabelRedoAvaliable](bool bAvailable)
    {
        if (bAvailable)
        {
            poLabelRedoAvaliable->setText("redo available");
        }
        else {
            poLabelRedoAvaliable->setText("redo not available");
        }
    });

    connect(poTextEdit, &QTextEdit::undoAvailable,
            [poLabelUndoAvaliable](bool bAvailable)
    {
        if (bAvailable)
        {
            poLabelUndoAvaliable->setText("undo available");
        }
        else {
            poLabelUndoAvaliable->setText("undo not available");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @Vadim Chernetsov, do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: Yes I need. Is there an opportunity to obtain an access to **undo/redo history** in `QTextEdit`?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov, I don't think Qt provides access to the undo/redo buffer. anyway please accept my answer if it works for you. thanks.